# understanding adminhtml url paths

Tags: magento, config, adminhtml

I am following [this tutorial from alan storm "magento_admin_hello_world_revisited"](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited) and it has been a great help in understanding the basics in putting together something for the admin section. Unfortunately, I'm left feeling a little confused on setting the URL path and as a result I have got a 404 error when I click on my link in the menu bar.

The tutorial says that I need to add

```
<action>adminhtml/Adminprefcentre/index</action>
```

to my adminHtml.xml for the menu link. Later in the tutorial it mentions that I need to add

```
<Adminprefcentre after="Mage_Adminhtml">Adminprefcentre</Adminprefcentre>
```

to my config.xml (NOTE: I have included the other relevant nodes described in the article into the config.xml).

As I was adding the `<action>` node I took that to mean the link which will be clicked on from the menu bar. As I added the `<Adminprefcentre>` node I believed that meant it was something to do with rewriting the admin frontName which is mentioned. Is this wrong?

I have created a controller in the usual way Name_Module_AdminprefcentreController and given it an action of indexAction.

When I click on my link in the menu bar i get `.../admin/adminprefcentre/index/key/ae6a...` and a 404 not found.

I am obviously misunderstanding what is being taught so

1 - what is the section that I am adding to my config.xml file doing?

2 - where should I look to resolve my 404 message?

Answer (score 0):

In config.xml

```
<config>
  .....
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <MagePal_Adminprefcentre before="Mage_Adminhtml">MagePal_Adminprefcentre_Adminhtml</MagePal_Adminprefcentre>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>    
    </routers>
  </admin>
```

Your Controller path

> /app/code/local/MagePal/Adminprefcentre/controllers/Adminhtml/AdminprefcentreController.php

in adminhtml.xml

```
<children>
    <adminprefcentre module="adminprefcentre">
        <title>menu title</title>
        <sort_order>15</sort_order> 
        <children>                                        
            <magepal_adminprefcentre module="adminprefcentre">
                <title>Submenu Title</title>
                <sort_order>15</sort_order> 
                <action>adminhtml/adminprefcentre</action> <!-- call index action in your controller -->
```